# Implementing WebRTC on WebView with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I'm developing an app which I need to include WebRTC using the WebView of Android. According to this article: [https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview] it is fully supported since WebView v36. (I'm testing on an Android 5.1.1 / Chrome 54 / Mobile Safari 537.36. And I confirm that it works on the standalone Chrome browser).

As of now, viewing of WebRTC works.

However, **broadcasting** (capturing video from the camera and sending it to the server) **does not work**. Note: it works on the standalone Chrome on the same Android.

I've included all these permissions in the codenameone_settings.properties file:

```
android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="true"/>\
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="true" />\
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true" />\
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="true" />\
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="true" />\
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" android:required="true" />\
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" android:required="true" />\
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true"/>\
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />\
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true"/>\
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />\
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />
```

1. Is this the way to activate all the necessary Android permissions.
2. What do you think is causing the WebRTC not to function properly?

The WebView is called by the BrowserComponent class.

I understand that Android code is translated to native code and I believe that there is a way to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just took a look at a couple of examples ([here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/blob/master/webrtc-example/app/src/main/java/com/google/chrome/android/webrtcsample/MainActivity.java#L144-L163) and [here](https://github.com/onsip/chromium-webview-samples), and it looks like the webview needs to grant some permissions in order to allow webrtc to work.

I have made a [small change](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/e86f42c58739711c6cbe1663cd9e677bb7517bb7) to our Android port that should allow you to grant these permissions. You just need to specify the origin in which permissions should be allowed. You would do this by setting the "android.WebView.grantPermissionsFrom" display property to the URL (or space delimited URLs) that you want to grant the permissions on.

e.g.

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty(
        "android.WebView.grantPermissionsFrom", 
        "https://www.example.com/"
);
```

Call this in your app's init() or start() method.

**NOTE** These changes won't be available until the next server update.  I'm not sure exactly when that will be since the bootcamp is underway right now.  Usually it is every Friday, but it may be delayed until the first week of May due to the bootcamp.

Comment: How can I know if it has been pushed into the update?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice this until now, we push an update once a week normally on a Friday unless explicitly announced otherwise

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried many times/approaches to load a url with webrtc without success because this was missing. In [this change](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/e86f42c58739711c6cbe1663cd9e677bb7517bb7), perhaps the condition to check `allowedOrigins` should also print a message to ask developer to set `android.WebView.grantPermissionsFrom` if `allowedOrigins == null`