# webRTC-video streaming implementation in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Good day all
Please I'll like to know if there is a way one can implement webRTC(live video streaming) using codename one, as its not clear how this can be achieved using the browserComponent. Thanks

Comment: Did you see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541962/implementing-webrtc-on-webview-with-codename-one was it helpful or do you need more information?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.    The link provided in that question leads to a page that doesn't exist. I'll also want to know if there is a way I can include a link to a JavaScript webRTC library as there seems to be a lot of options for that using JavaScript. Thanks again

Comment: Within the HTML you can include any JavaScript you want. The trick is to place the HTML in the html package (in root) then open it using the hierarchy method which allows you to use hierarchies.

Comment: thanks sir, I'll try using your advice